# Sending float over TCP

Tags: c++, tcp, floating-point

I need to send a series of floats over a TCP socket.

Firstly, is it safe to assume that most platforms (e.g off the shelf Windows PC/Laptop) and architectures represent floats in the same way (i.e IEEE 754)?

If so, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
float a = 29.054;
int* b = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a);

//Store in byte array
```

Would this work?

Comment: I think you may run into undefined behavior due to [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650) with this code if you are compiling with GCC. My solution for this in the past was to make a custom int typedef that had the [`__may_alias__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute that explicitly allowed type punning (then I'd use that instead of `int`). MSVC does not have any strict aliasing optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

You can check [`std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) and fail to compile for platforms that use other representation

Answer (score 3):

It's probably safe to assume that *most* platforms support IEEE floats.  That implies that you don't care about the other platforms.  It will be mainly embedded systems that won't have an IEEE-compliant floating point maths processor.

Floats can suffer from endianness problems just like integers.  Make sure that you define what endianness you are using (big endian or little endian), and ensure that the numbers are byte swapped on platforms that need it.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the second part of the question, do you think using a reinterpret_cast is the right way to go? I assume I can also cast to a char buffer, instead of an int?

Comment: And out of interest, are most platforms moving towards IEEE floats?

Comment: @19172281 reinterpret_cast is not enough, you have to manually swap bytes before reinterpreting if the network byte order doesn't match your system's. Though to be fair Big Endian CPUs are not very common these days in desktop / laptop computers; PowerPC was the last mainstream Big Endian system I remember offhand

Comment: Assuming the byte order is correct and doesn't need swapping, is the reinterpret_cast appropriate?

Comment: Also, how would you swap the byte order before casting? Why couldn't you swap after the cast?

Comment: @19172281 swapping after the cast would require going back to treating the float value as a char* again, you may as well do it before you interpret the data as float. Technically [bit endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bit_endianness) is a thing too (in addition to byte endianness) but that might not matter for your case. I can't think of anything else offhand. Remember to stick with char* or you will need to deal with strict aliasing (which is, admittedly not that complicated, just an attribute).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. After the reinterpret cast (from float to char*), we have a char* which can be swapped into the correct order. Could you perhaps add some code to your answer to better illustrate please? :)

Comment: @19172281 I'd probably swap bytes by making a small buffer that's the [size of a float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524737) (which is platform dependent) and literally swap by writing to array (byte) indexes.  I'd recommend putting static asserts in your code to make sure your assumptions about the size of a float are correct. Or if saving space isn't an issue, write it to a string. It's hard to do code in comments and SE.SE probably isn't the best site for that anyway to be honest. See also: [How to serialize a float?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/201675/)

Comment: @19172281 typo there, I meant "swap before casting from char* to float*" for reading from the network, "swap after casting from float to char*" for writing to the network.

Comment: Ahhhh, that clears it all up. So to send the float, reinterpret_cast from float to char* and then swap byte order if necessary.